# Nationality/Residence on US credit report?

Tags: united-states, credit-report

Is the Nationality and Residence Status saved on my credit report? Do and should I report a change in my status report to the credit bureaus or to the issuing bank?

I am asking because I know that for example Citibank treats Non-Immigrants different from immigrants/citizens. They simply offer different credit cards. So I think they somehow have a distinction between different types of visas. Is Citibank an exception or does it go all the way up to my credit report?

Answer (score 1):

**Is the Nationality and Residence Status saved on my credit report?** 
No. Your credit report [does not report](http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/7-credit-report-myths-truth-1270.php) on your nationality or citizenship status.

**Do and should I report a change in my status report to the credit bureaus or to the issuing bank?**
I do not believe they would care. As long as you maintain your payments you should be fine. Of course, if your social security number is revoked, then the credit card companies would care.

**Is Citibank an exception or does it go all the way up to my credit report?**
Citibank could offer you a different credit card, but that's the same as offering different credit cards to low risk vs high risk applicants. If you "[have established a credit with a US based company](https://help.equifax.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/166/~/u.s.-credit-files-for-foreign-citizens-and-expatriates)" then you will have a credit report. But there isn't a difference in credit reports if you are a immigrant or a non-immigrant.

I hope that answers your questions.